# Show another view when user is log in Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

How can I go to next view, when user is log in and app remember session. I use this code:

```
if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()){
        //if are logged in so show another view
    }
```

but what I should write (in this place "if are logged in so show another view") to go automaticly to next view where is picture, name and other data from user? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some code being called when you successfully login the first time right? Just extract that code into a method and call it:

```
-(void) facebookLoginCallback
{ 
    //Do something 
}

if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
{
    [self facebookLoginCallback];
}
```

It's difficult to tell exactly what you should do as we don't know how your project is set up, but you probably want to do something like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: I need to go to the next view (excluding the first one) if the application remembers the user's log in.